# In the deduction theorem, what exactly is contained in $\Delta$?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus, axioms

In the deduction theorem you'll sometimes see a specific set referred to as [$\Delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) or [$\Gamma$](https://mally.stanford.edu/tutorial/sentential.html) or [$U$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Deduction_Theorem), as used below:

$$\Delta, A \vdash B \implies \Delta \vdash A \to B$$

I've seen this set $\Delta$ referred to as a set of "assumptions", a set of "hypotheses", a set of "axioms", a set of "non-logical axioms", a set of "postulates", a set of "schemata", etc.

I'm not entirely sure what this means formally, if these are all actually saying the same thing -- but if that's the case and an "assumption" is the same as a "non-logical axiom" I'm not sure how this differs from a regular "axiom" that we normally build right into the system to begin with.

Especially when we define a proof as a sequence of lines $\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3, ..., \varphi_n$, where "each line is either an axiom or theorem", I can't tell if this includes non-logical axioms / assumptions, or if we have some special name for the results acquired through modus ponens (are these theorems?). I know a "theorem" for example is composed of axioms and other theorems via logical connectives but I don't know if this includes non-logical axioms or modus ponens results.

Furthermore I don't really know where these assumptions/hypotheses/non-logical axioms "come from" -- if they're invoked out of thin air $\vdash \phi$, or if they may not necessarily be sound/true or what have you.

Can anyone shed some light on this? What's contained in $\Delta$ exactly? Where do they come from exactly? What is each line of a proof allowed to be exactly?

Comment: The members of $\Delta$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo This seems to go against our previous conversation though where we say each line of a proof must be an axiom/theorem and cannot be an assumption (which I presume comes from $\Delta$). In the usual proof of deduction theorem I do see that $\varphi_k$ (a proof line) is allowed to be an element of $\Delta$. Even so, where are these arbitrary members coming from? Assumed/asserted out of nothing / the empty set?

Comment: Formulas; in the context of formalized theory, like e.g. first order arithmetic, the arithmetical axioms (the first-order version of Peano's axioms) are in $\Delta$.

Comment: Yes. In the presence of $\Delta$, each line in a proof is an axiom of a theorem of (the theory) $\Delta$.

Comment: Just as in regular mathematics. If proving results in group theory you typically use not just logical axioms, but also the axioms of group theory.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo So for example if we were doing a proof in set theory, $\Delta$ might contain "non-logical axioms" such as these? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zermelo-FraenkelAxioms.html

Comment: And when we refer to each step of a proof being an axiom or theorem, by "axiom" here we refer to both logical and non-logical axioms? And theorems are (ultimately) just axioms (both logical and non-logical) pieced together with logical connectives?

Comment: NO, in the context of e.g. first order set theory, *axioms* in a derivation are logical axioms, while "mathematical" axioms (e.g. the specific axioms of ZFC) are in the set of *assumptions* of derivations i.e. in $\Delta$.

Comment: The complete definition of *proof sequence* in a formalized theory for $\Delta \vdash \varphi$ is : " a sequence $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ where $\varphi_n=\varphi$ and each $\varphi_i$ is either a *logical* axiom or a formula in $\Delta$ or derived from previous formulas of the sequence by way of *inference rules* (e.g. *modus ponens*)."

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the formulas derived from modus ponens, are these simply... formulas? Not axioms, not theorems?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Which part are you saying yes to?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't understand how that differs from what I was saying? Aren't the axioms I linked the "specific axioms of ZFC" that I am asking are included in $\Delta$?

Comment: To your comments: Yes, $\Delta$ typically consists of the non-logical axioms relevant to whatever you are doing (such as the ZFC axioms if doing set theory). I hadn't seen your other comment,  so: in a proof each step is either a logical axiom or a non-logical axiom (a member of $\Delta$), or comes from previous steps via the rules of your system (which I suppose up to this point it is just via modus ponens). But you see, theorems are not just axioms "pieced together via connectives", but any statements you can derive from the axioms using the rules of your system.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo So the results of modus ponens would be a theorem, connecting axioms/non-logical axioms/other theorems together would be a theorem, substitution of any of these things into each other would be a theorem, etc. A theorem basically being "anything derived", axioms being things we invoke either directly from the set of non-logical axioms $\Delta$ or logical axioms taken from $\emptyset$?

Comment: Perfect; so why not simply check on a textbook ? See e.g. van Dalen, page 34: "**Definition 2.4.2** The relation $Γ \vdash ϕ$ between sets of propositions and propositions is defined as follows: there is a derivation with conclusion $ϕ$ and with all hypotheses [or *assumptions*] in $Γ$. We say that $ϕ$ is *derivable from* $Γ$ . If $Γ = \emptyset$, we write $\vdash ϕ$, and we say that $ϕ$ is a *theorem*."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I did see that definition on that page (one of the many reasons I made this question); it seemed inconsistent with what I am reading elsewhere, or at the very least incomplete, which is why I am trying to clarify and get a very very specific definition for what everything is here

Comment: @user525966 - What do you mean by "it seemed inconsistent with what I am reading elsewhere, or at the very least incomplete"? In my opinion, Mauro Allegranza and Andrés Caicedo explained very well what a derivation is, and what assumptions and logical axioms are.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Because I often see $\vdash \phi$ referred to as an axiom (in this case I suppose a "logical axiom"), not a theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just some set of statements, that's it.

Where they come from, you need not be concerned about, unless you apply all of this logic theory to something real, but in logic itself, we don't care where the statements come from, whether they are true, or what they even mean.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that we can prove things with faulty assumptions in $\Delta$?

Comment: @user525966 You bet!  If I assume that pigs fly, I can prove that pigs fly.  But this is exactly why I say that logicians don't care as to what is actually true. They only care about logical entailment.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\Delta, A\vdash B}{\Delta \vdash A\to B}$$

The $\Delta$ is a list of predicates.   The deduction theorem states that if the list $\Delta$ and $A$ does syntactically entail $B$, then you can infer that the $\Delta$ will be a list which syntactically entails $A\to B$.

---

> I'm not sure how this differs from a regular "axiom" that we normally build right into the system to begin with.

They are not tautologies built into the proof system but are contingencies made for a particular proof.

---

So if you can show that $A\to (C\to B), C, A\vdash B$ then you may infer that $A\to (C\to B), C \vdash A\to B$

Comment: That's sort of my question though, what are these "predicates" exactly? I understand what the theorem itself is saying, but my question is more about what $\Delta$ is and its role.

Comment: Are "contingencies" the same as "unproven assumptions that may be true, may be false"? i.e. something of the form $\vdash \varphi$ but not necessarily sound?

Comment: "Predicates" sounds strange to me in this context. Are you sure you didn't mean that $\Delta$ is a list of _propositions_? Or perhaps _premises_?

Comment: How is Δ a list of predicates if the context is propositional calculus?